# cloud 9 IDE says killed

Tags: cloud9-ide

My cloud9 terminal responds with just "killed" in different situations.  Sometimes it is when running rails server as mentioned in other posts and sometimes when executing bundle exec test.   Other posts indicate that this is a memory issue.   However, is there anyway to actually confirm this.  Does cloud 9 have any logs to indicate that this is the underlying issue?

Comment: You can run 'top' and look at the RES column to see how much memory your app/s are using, you'll notice it gets killed when it hits the memory limit of your workspace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally when cloud9 responds with just "Killed", it means that lots of processes are running at the same time on cloud9 and cloud9 is not able to allocate the memory to this current process so it just kills the current executing process.

If you need to check what all processes are running currently on cloud9 you can check this by executing command ps -ef.

Whenever you suffer from such problem then execute the command "kill -9 `pgrep ruby`" (the back-ticks are required). This will terminate all the spring processes and then you can again start up with your process by executing the command `rails server -b $IP -p $PORT` and then execte bundle exec rake test or whatever command that was not being able to get executed earlier.

Answer (score 0):

In case the solution above doesn't work:

I had the same problem and killing the spring process didn't help. I managed to fix that only after I found that *two* different versions of the gem 'spring' were installed on my IDE drive, and then uninstalled the older one.

This is unlikely to be a wide-spread case, though.